# Thread-safe find and remove an object from a Collection

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

I wonder how can I do something like the following

```
class MyCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
    @Nullable E findAndRemove(Predicate<E> predicate) {
        for (E e : this) {
            if (predicate.test(e)) {
                remove(e);
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

in a thread-safe manner. It doesn't really have to be a `Collection`, as the only needed operations are `add` and `findAndRemove`. Note that

- `removeIf` is unrelated as it removes *all* matching elements and gives nothing in return
- let's assume that synchronization isn't good enough
- `CopyOnWriteArrayList` might do, but it's Javadoc says "efficient when ... traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations", which definitely isn't true here
- it's not allowed to return the same element twice (unless re-added in the meantime), which could easily happen when using`CopyOnWriteArrayList` naively
- which matching element gets returned doesn't matter

Concerning premature optimization and XY problem: *Yes, I know!* I went into this when fooling around with something I may or mayn't need one day, but I find this problem interesting per se.

Comment: You can use a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`, to prevent any mutations, when another thread is already mutating the `Collection`. (or just `remove`-operations, if that is enough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only need the `add` and `findAndRemove` methods, some type of concurrent hash is a natural choice, as there has been a good implementation (`ConcurrentHashMap`) since Java 1.5. Now since we don't actually need a `Map` but rather a `Set` we can just use (since Java 8 anyway) `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` to create a concurrent set using the same implementation as the concurrent map.

Then, given a concurrent set, we can pretty much use your loop above, and optimistically remove the element, and then simply continue searching on failure (which means that a thread concurrently removed the element that matched):

```
class MyCollection<E> {

  private Set<E> underlying = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

  void add(E elem) {
    underlying.add(elem);
  }

  @Nullable E findAndRemove(Predicate<E> predicate) {
    for (E e : underlying) {
        if (predicate.test(e) && remove(e)) {
          return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }   
}
```

The only real change with respect to your example code is that we check the result of [`Set.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) to see if the element was *actually* removed. For the concurrent set, this works "safely" - i.e., only the thread which actually removed the object will see `true`, so this set will correctly return the element only if it was actually removed, and no other thread will then be able to return that element.

It should satisfy all your requirements and perform as well as the underlying concurrent map implementations, which on modern JDKs is "very well".

Note that the use of a `Set` implies that duplicate elements aren't allowed. It wasn't clear from your description whether you planned to support duplicates or not, but if you did, you could use the same approach built on a concurrent multimap<sup>1</sup>, or simply using `ConcurrentHashMap<E, AtomicInteger>`, where the `AtomicInteger` value a reference count of the number of elements with the same key, the `add` and `findAndRemove` methods manipulate the reference count<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> In a quick search, however, I couldn't find an obvious open source implementation of a concurrent multimap. Note that you don't actually need a capital-M `Multimap` implementation with all its functionality - you really only need "some multiset" with the ability to add an element, iterate over available elements, and "remove" an element (i.e., decrement its refcount in the set).

<sup>2</sup> I'm actually glossing over a few details of the reference counted implementation since in this case there is a possible race between the thread that decrements the refcount to zero and any thread calling `add` for the same element which may increment the refcount above zero (but the entry has already been removed). This can be avoided but I don't go into details yet since it isn't clear if you want to support duplicates.

Comment: That's much simpler than I thought, thank you. `+++` Just FTR: I need no duplicates. I guess, there's no good `ConcurrentMultimap ` for [these reasons](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/135#issuecomment-61312052). Your `ConcurrentMultiset` could get tricky, as an entry should be removed when the counter reaches zero, but other threads may increment it in the meantime.

Comment: @maaartinus - yup it gets tricky, which is what I was hinting at the second footnote above. I think you can still do it, leveraging `remove(key, value)` on the decrement value path (comparing with `value` to `AtomicInteger(1)`), and a "double check" on the increment path, but at that point it might just be better to copy/paste a CHM implementation and build the methods you want into the existing logic (for example, with striped-lock CHM this is easy).

Answer (score 1):

You can use read and write lock for mutation in collection or you can use `ConcurrentHashMap` to represent collection as set.

```
Set set =Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Boolean>());
```